# sql that identifies which account numbers have multiple agents

Tags: sql, sql-server

I dont think a count will work here, can someone help me get an sql that identifies which account numbers have multiple agents, more than two agents in the where condition.

```
    AGENT_NAME          ACCOUNT_NUMBER

    Clemons, Tony       123
    Cipollo, Michael    123
    Jepsen, Sarah       567
    Joanos, James       567
    McMahon, Brian      890
    Novak, Jason        437
    Ralph, Melissa      197
    Reitwiesner, John   221
    Roman, Marlo        123
    Rosenzweig, Marcie  890
```

Results should be something like this.

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER    AGENT_NAME         
123               Cipollo, Michael
123               Roman, Marlo
123               Clemons, Tony      
890               Rosenzweig, Marcie
890               McMahon, Brian
567               Joanos, James
567               Jepsen, Sarah
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select t.account_number, t.agent_name
from (select t.*, min(agent_name) over (partition by account_number) as minan,
             max(agent_name) over (partition by account_number) as maxan
      from table t
     ) t
where minan <> maxan;
```

If you know the agent names are never duplicated, you could just do:

```
select t.account_number, t.agent_name
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by account_number) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table name is test, this should pull all the records with duplicate ACCOUNT_NUMBER:

```
select * from test where ACCOUNT_NUMBER in 
       (select ACCOUNT_NUMBER from test 
           group by ACCOUNT_NUMBER having 
        count(ACCOUNT_NUMBER)>1)
order by ACCOUNT_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

Using count function u can get the result

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
  (
     AGENT_NAME     VARCHAR(100),
     ACCOUNT_NUMBER INT
  )

INSERT INTO #TEMP
VALUES      ('CLEMONS, TONY',123),
            ('CIPOLLO, MICHAEL',123),
            ('JEPSEN, SARAH',567),
            ('JOANOS, JAMES',567),
            ('MCMAHON, BRIAN',890),
            ('NOVAK, JASON',437),
            ('RALPH, MELISSA',197),
            ('REITWIESNER, JOHN',221),
            ('ROMAN, MARLO',123),
            ('ROSENZWEIG, MARCIE',890)

SELECT a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,a.AGENT_NAME
FROM   #TEMP A
       JOIN(SELECT COUNT(1) CNT,
                   ACCOUNT_NUMBER
            FROM   #TEMP
            GROUP  BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER) B
         ON A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = B.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
WHERE  B.CNT != 1
```